# i'm having trouble drawing anthropomorphic animal heads

Tags: drawing

i was asked to draw an anthropomorphic character for someone, but i'm having trouble drawing it's mouth part from an angle, could there be a guide how to do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you look up **comparative anatomy**, with regards to the species you are merging (a human and whatever animal/animals you have in mind), and the body part you have problems with (like the jaw, or the skull as a whole, etc).